# Crack The Clock Code

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

Can you guess the letters in all the question mark locations on this clock?
Note the actual shown time is not relevant.

Comment: By guess, the topmost is CA?

Comment: was that made in excel? @_@

Comment: This feels too-broad to me.

Answer (score 1):

This was simply related to the ranking of the world countries by size- first and last letter: 1 to 12

1 Russia    R A

2 Canada    C A

3 USA       U A

4 China     C A

5 Brazil    B L

6 Australia A A

7 India     I A

8 Argentina A A

9 Kazkastan K N

10 Algeria  A A

11 Congo    C O  or D O ( Dem Rep of)

12 Mexico   M O

There are some questions about the last 2 ones in some refs.

Comment: Why the clock? Which clues points towards the solution? I think this was more of a "guess what am I thinking" puzzle.

Comment: Agreed with Tech. This was just a picture and no relevant clues in the whole question that even points to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution (-always better than just let things linger forever-), but I agree that with the solution given this puzzle still does not look very good. Too much of guessing, too few clues to indicate where to start, and no "verification" that can at least afterwards have a "Oh, that's really the only thing which fits" moment. So, not taking it personally, but I think it is not a good puzzle. (+1 for the answer, -1 for the question)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I found - (This may be slightly off from the OP's intended solution, but does provide the idea he has in mind. I guess)

> Take a couple of pairs from the clock starting from 12 o clock. One pair when decoded with the other as a key using Vigenere Cipher, gives the plain text as itself.

Example

> KN $\rightarrow$ AA(Key) $\rightarrow$ KN (12-1)
>  CA $\rightarrow$ AA(Key) $\rightarrow$ CA (2-3)
>  CA $\rightarrow$ AA(Key) $\rightarrow$ CA (4-5)
>  AA $\rightarrow$ AA(Key) $\rightarrow$ AA (6-7)
>  KN $\rightarrow$ AA(Key) $\rightarrow$ KN (8-9)
>  AA $\rightarrow$ AA(Key) $\rightarrow$ AA (10-11)

And the clock gives

> [image]

Comment: Isn't this just another way of saying "one in each pair of hours is AA"?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yeah. The first pair could be CA/AA as well. I will leave the pattern search thing to better brains unless its too broad :-) I think I've got the Vigenere involved.

Comment: @Techidiot Now take this and go find the pet ;)